# SQL Server : return column names based on a record's value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm hoping someone has a quick suggestion/solution to the following, based on the following sample table:

```
|Field1 |Field2 |Field3 |Field4 |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| 1     | 0     | 0     | 1     |
```

I was hoping to be able to build a query to return the column names where their value (based on a single record) = 1. This, without leaning on cursors or temp tables.

I.e. I would like the following output:

```
Field1
Field4
```

I've been trying to do various joins against `sys.columns` (and `sys.tables`), but so far to little avail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also use `Cross apply`

```
SELECT Cname
FROM   Tablename
       CROSS apply (VALUES('Field1',Field1),
                          ('Field2',Field2),
                          ('Field3',Field3),
                          ('Field4',Field4)) ca (cname, data)
WHERE  data = 1
```

To work dynamically use this.

```
CREATE TABLE test
  (
     Field1 INT,
     Field2 INT,
     Field3 INT,
     Field4 INT
  )

INSERT INTO test
VALUES      ( 1,0,0,1 )

DECLARE @collist VARCHAR(max)='',
        @sql     NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @collist += '(''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''',' + COLUMN_NAME + '),'
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'test'
       AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'Field%'
       AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'

SELECT @collist = LEFT(@collist, Len(@collist) - 1)

SET @sql ='
SELECT Cname
FROM   test
       CROSS apply (VALUES' + @collist
          + ') ca (cname, data)
WHERE  data = 1 '

EXEC Sp_executesql
  @sql
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `union all`, for instance:

```
select 'Field1' from table t where Field1 = 1 union all
select 'Field2' from table t where Field2 = 1 union all
select 'Field3' from table t where Field3 = 1 union all
select 'Field4' from table t where Field4 = 1;
```

Comment: That would certainly work, and I appreciate the suggestion, but I forgot to mention that I also need to do this dynamically against tables based on a given criteria. E.g. I should want to query a table of my choosing and return all column names where the name starts with 'Field' ('Field%') and its value = 1.

Comment: +One. Perhaps `UNION` would be better than `UNION ALL` if OP does not want `Field1` repeated endlessly for endless rows that match `Field1 = 1`. i.e. *Does the column contain a 1 in any row*.

Comment: @ta.speot.is . . . The OP specifically mentions that the value is based on a single record.  There would need to be a `and recordnum = xxx` in the logic.

Comment: @BjørnH.Sandvik . . . You would have to do that using dynamic SQL.

Comment: I wound up creating dynamic queries in VB. I find building dynamic queries in T-SQL is a little unsexy. Thanks though!

Comment: *I find building dynamic queries in T-SQL is a little unsexy **so I used Visual Basic instead**.*

Comment: Crisp and simple.