# SQL Server - Find col's name by specified value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have couple of columns with specified names. I need to select name of column, where is specified value.

Example:

```
-----------------------------------
id| a col | b col | c col | d col |
-----------------------------------
1 |   N   |   N   |   A   |   N   |
2 |   A   |   N   |   N   |   N   |
3 |   N   |   A   |   N   |   N   |
```

I need to get result like

```
--------------------
id | column's name |
--------------------
1  |     c col     |
2  |     a col     |
3  |     b col     |
```

There are more columns in table, so I need to specify columns which should be used for this. How can I do that in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: u should look up pivot or unpivot https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server : return column names based on a record's value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285569/sql-server-return-column-names-based-on-a-records-value)

Comment: Storing the same "type" of data in multiple columns is usually a sign of a broken data model - often accompanied by some of your *data* instead ending up as *metadata* - such as here, where data you want to write queries about has become embedded in column *names*. It would be better, if possible, to fix the data model so that all data is modelled *as data*.

Answer (score 0):

[UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) should be enough:

```
SELECT  id,
        col
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    ) as p
UNPIVOT (
    [value] FOR col IN ([a col], [b col], [c col], [d col])
) as unpvt
WHERE [value] = 'A'
```

Output:

```
id  col
1   c col
2   a col
3   b col
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNPIVOT query like below

```
declare @q varchar(max)
set @q='select id,columnname from '+
'(select id,columnname,data from '+
'(select * from tablename)t '+
'UNPIVOT '+
'(data for columnname in ( '+
 stuff((select ',['+c.name +'] ' from sys.columns c join sys.tables t 
 on c.object_id=t.object_id and t.name like 'tablename' FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
 +')) u)t where data like ''A'''
exec @q
```