# How to use one table as a filter from other and generate a new one in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

say that I have a table that needs to be used as a filter table(table A) vs other one which reads data from a linkedserver (table b). The result of the filtering will generate a third table, the thing is I can not figure it out how to apply this filtering correctly. I found reference from this link: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285569/sql-server-return-column-names-based-on-a-records-value)  but it does not onboard what I am looking for.
See as following:

Table A - data type in columns is Bit

`|Field1 |Field2 |Field3 |Field4 |CustomerCode|
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------------| 
| 1     | 0     | 0     | 1     |    c001     |`

Table B - data type in columns is varchar

`|FieldA |FieldB |FieldC |FieldD |CustomerCode | 
|------- |-------|-------|-------|-------------|
| aaaaa  | null | ccccc |ddddd   |    c001     |`

Then what I seeking is something like this:

`IF tableA.Field1 = 1 THEN NOT EMPTY tableB.FieldA
 Do an INSERT INTO tableC FieldI VALUES(tableB.FieldA)
 ELSE INSERT INTO tableC FieldI VALUES ('No Value Found')`

So this will ensure that for all fields from table A are equal 1, 
then for table B data can not be null, if data is null just insert that message: 'No Value Found'; if data is not null, then just place the data from table B to that table C.
I am starting with SQL and mostly I am missing something that could make it easier to digest this issue.

Thanks

Comment: What is the relationship between Table A and Table B?  I don't see one.

Comment: It seems that you want to conditionally insert records from Table B into Table C, but using information in Table A.  In order for us to be able to help you, you need to tell us how Tables A and B are _related_.

Comment: Very important fact, I made the update now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INSERT INTO tableC ... SELECT FROM`.  Something like this should work:

```
INSERT INTO tableC
SELECT COALESCE(t1.FieldA, 'No Value Found'),
       COALESCE(t1.FieldB, 'No Value Found'),
       COALESCE(t1.FieldC, 'No Value Found'),
       COALESCE(t1.FieldD, 'No Value Found')
FROM TableB t1
INNER JOIN TableA t2
    ON t1.CustomerCode = t2.CustomerCode
WHERE t2.Field1 = 1 AND
      t2.Field2 = 1 AND
      t2.Field3 = 1 AND
      t2.Field4 = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort Tim, just guessing that at where statement it should say "t2.Field1...." instead of t1 ; I tried your method but is still not doing the insert at tableC

Comment: `but is still not doing the insert at tableC` ... what is actually happening?

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay I worked it out with the example you provided, it is doing the filtering correctly thanks