# SQL - Find column name based on occurrence of values in rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

This is my table test.
Here 9 to 22 is the column names.
I want to get the column names of first and last occurrence of data 1.
How do I do it?

For example in first row I have data 1 for the columns 9 and 10 ,so for this row I'm expecting to fetch 9 and 10.
Similarly in the last row the first occurrence of data 1 is in  9 and last occurrence is in 17 column accordingly I should get 9 and 17 as output.
tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285569/sql-server-return-column-names-based-on-a-records-value) question but no luck!

Comment: Looks more like a C++/C# kind of a problem. What does first and last mean? SQL Server is not for solving matrix issues.

Comment: Please figure it out yourself. Or if you have done some research, post it in your question. Show what you have already searched and tried already. Ask a detailed question.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you might need to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Look at `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @InputTable Table
(
 A9 varchar(1),
 A10 varchar(1),
 A11 varchar(1),
 A12 varchar(1),
 A13 varchar(1),
 A14 varchar(1),
 A15 varchar(1),
 A16 varchar(1),
 A17 varchar(1),
 A18 varchar(1),
 A19 varchar(1),
 A20 varchar(1),
 A21 varchar(1),
 A22 varchar(1)            
)

Insert into @InputTable values
(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0),
(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1),
(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0),
(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0),
(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1),
(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)


Select concat('A',8+CHARINDEX('1',Derivedcolumn)) [First], concat('A',23-charindex('1',reverse(derivedcolumn)))[Last]  from
(
Select A9+A10+A11+A12+A13+A14+A15+A16+A17+A18+A19+A20+A21+A22 DerivedColumn,* from @InputTable
)InputTable
```

Combine every column, use CHARINDEX to find 1st occurrence and for the last occurrence, reverse the string and find the 1st occurrence in the reversed string which will be the last in our case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed number of columns you could

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t (id int, col1 int,col2 int,col3 int,col4 int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t values
    -> (1,1,1,0,0),
    -> (2,0,0,1,1);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select t.id, concat(col1,col2,col3,col4), instr(concat(col1,col2,col3,col4),1) firstcol,
    ->  5 - instr(reverse(concat(col1,col2,col3,col4)),1) lastcol
    -> from t;
+------+-----------------------------+----------+---------+
| id   | concat(col1,col2,col3,col4) | firstcol | lastcol |
+------+-----------------------------+----------+---------+
|    1 | 1100                        |        1 |       2 |
|    2 | 0011                        |        3 |       4 |
+------+-----------------------------+----------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```