# Find a value in a SQL Server table and get next column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server and I need to find the column that has the same value (call it 'b67') for all rows, but I don't now the column name (because the name of the column changes very often). I need to find this column and ask to the next column the other part of the value (the 2 columns are always together).

Example of table (imagine the same but with more `'coso'`):

```
ID |  coso1   |   c45   |   coso2     |   b63  |  Coso3 | d28
---+----------+---------+-------------+--------+--------+----
1  |   b63    |  1      |   d28       |  5     |   c45  |  3
2  |   b63    |  4      |   d28       |  6     |   c45  |  5  
3  |   b63    |  67     |   d28       |  1     |   c45  |  2 
4  |   b63    |  34     |   d28       |  5     |   c45  |  6
5  |   b63    |  8      |   d28       |  6     |   c45  |  9
```

Comment: Why do the column names change? Seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Becouse the people who controls the database, put new columns and modify all, for example now the column 'b67', have the things of the 'c45',

Comment: How exactly the next column name is defined?

Comment: Tell your boss you can't work in a project like this.

Comment: in theory is defined with the value of the last, but now not

Comment: For this kind of random structure better to go for nosql other then It's going to more complex to manage in future as now.

Comment: not clear to me.explain your requirement with example.

Comment: You can use dynamic sql for that. You can get the order of the columns in sys.columns view

Comment: Get all columns of the table, prepare a dynamic sql, Check for value in dynamic sql. You shall be able to get columns from SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS or SELECT * FROM sys.all_columns by joining it with OBJECT id of table. Alternatively, you can see if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285569/sql-server-return-column-names-based-on-a-records-value

Comment: *people who controls the database* ... have a sit down with these folks and let them know schemas should remain intact after initial database design and that relational databases are structured, standardized, and centralized repositories and not spreadsheets or text files. Otherwise your queries will be very complex as posted answers show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear what exactly do you need, but take a look to that sql:

```
create table test_columns
(
coso1 char(3),
c45 int,
coso2 char(3),
b63 int
);

insert into test_columns values ('b63', 1, 'd28', 5)

DECLARE @column_id INT,
        @name varchar(200),
        @query varchar(max),
        @next_column varchar(200)
DECLARE @cursor CURSOR
SET @cursor = CURSOR FOR
select name, column_id from sys.columns where object_name(object_id) = 'test_columns' and name like 'coso%'
OPEN @cursor
FETCH NEXT
FROM @cursor INTO @name, @column_id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @query = 'SELECT 1 FROM dbo.test_columns HAVING  COUNT(distinct ' + @name + ') = 1';
    EXEC (@query);
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 1) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @next_column = name FROM sys.columns where object_name(object_id) = 'test_columns' and column_id = @column_id + 1;
    SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @next_column + ', ' + @name + '  FROM dbo.test_columns';

    EXEC (@query);

    END
FETCH NEXT
FROM @cursor INTO @name, @column_id
END
CLOSE @cursor
DEALLOCATE @cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build dynamic sql to test each column.
I have used `DM_EXEC_DESCRIBE_FIRST_RESULT_SET` to get column names but you can use also `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE'`

I store column number, column name and the sql query to test the column in a temp (variable) table and then loop thro even columns to test the passed value.

It should work

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FIND_VAL (
    @ValuetoFind varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @TABLENAME VARCHAR(100) = 'MYTABLE'


    DECLARE @S TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, SQL_CMD VARCHAR(255), [NAME] VARCHAR(32))
    DECLARE @SQL_CMD NVARCHAR(255) = ''
    DECLARE @ID INT = 0
    DECLARE @C INT

    ;WITH
    C AS (
        SELECT * FROM SYS.DM_EXEC_DESCRIBE_FIRST_RESULT_SET('SELECT * FROM '+@TABLENAME,NULL,1) 
    ),
    S AS (
        SELECT COLUMN_ORDINAL, 'SET @CNT= CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM '+ @TABLENAME + ' WHERE ISNULL(' + [NAME] + ', '''')<>'''+@VALUETOFIND+''') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END' Q, [NAME]
        FROM C  
    )
    INSERT INTO @S
    SELECT * FROM S

    --SELECT * FROM @S

    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @S WHERE (ID % 2)=0 ORDER BY ID) BEGIN

        SELECT TOP 1 @ID=ID, @SQL_CMD = SQL_CMD FROM @S WHERE (ID % 2)=0 ORDER BY ID

        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL_CMD, N'@CNT INT OUTPUT', @CNT=@C OUTPUT

        IF @C = 1 BEGIN
            SELECT [NAME] FROM @S WHERE ID=@ID+1
            RETURN
        END

        DELETE FROM @S WHERE ID = @ID
    END
    SELECT NULL [NAME]
END
```

Output

```
NAME
c45
```