# How to push to an array inside of a JSON object in a JSONB column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the below data in a JSONB column in PostgreSQL.

```
{
    "myFirstDeck" : {
        "cards": [1, 2, 3]
    }
}
```

I would like to use one of the inbuilt JSONB PostgreSQL functions to push/append an integer to the cards array inside of the myFirstDeck key/object.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

I have tried various variations using jsonb_set and concatenation but am struggling to get it working.

Comment: `SELECT jsonb_set('{"myFirstDeck" : {"cards": [1, 2, 3]}}' :: jsonb, '{myFirstDeck,cards}' :: text[], to_jsonb('new_jsonb' :: text))`. Result : `{"myFirstDeck": {"cards": "new_jsonb"}}`. see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)

Comment: [Two questions about card decks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75075330/how-to-search-an-entry-in-a-table-and-return-the-column-name-or-index-in-postgre/75075489#75075489). Hmm. Same advice as I gave to that answer: use a join table.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This solution replaces the cards array with a new one, is there not an inbuilt way to append/push to the array without having to replace the original array with a new one?

Comment: "*I have tried various variations using jsonb_set and concatenation*" - please show us those attempts so that we can help you with them

Comment: I think a join table like @Schwern suggested is an easy solution to my query, thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jsonb_insert()`

The following appends the value 4 at the end of the array

```
jsonb_insert(the_column, '{myFirstDeck,cards,-1}', to_jsonb(4), true)
```

---

But if you find yourself doing this a lot you should seriously consider using a properly normalized data  model rather than abusing JSON.